# URL into Array (regardless of location)

Tags: php

I need to put an URL (something along the lines of mysite.com/this/is/my/url) into an Array in a way that if the site itself is in a subfolder (something like mysite.com/a-folder/this/is/my/url) then it would not take "a-folder" into that array and if mod_rewrite is not enabled it wouldn't take index.php either. I know how to put the url into an array but I have no idea how to exclude items from it. Any help is appreciated.

My final goal would be to use an array instead of $_GET, but since the array changes when the site is in a subfolder, root, with or without mod_rewrite it wouldn't live up to my expectations. I need to be able to create an array that doesn't change the /this/is/my/url, so when I for example echo $arr['0'] it would return "this" instead of "a-folder" or "index.php".

Comment: Did I explain myself poorly or it's just not possible to exclude things from an array?

Comment: Just strictly with an `array()`, your approach seems... *weird*. Why not use a function or object method with some some logic to determine your **final** array's characteristics?

Comment: I explained a little more in the original question, maybe you get my point now.

Comment: Are you trying to create a versatile application that will function as if mod_rewrite is enabled even if it isn't?

Comment: Yes, that's almost exactly what I'm going for. But It's a tiny bit more than just mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of string functions you can use (stristr, strpos, etc...).

You could also try regex, but I think its generally agreed that is overkill.

But without understanding your question this is the best I can do.

Edit: Still a little confused, but maybe this?

```
foreach($array as $key=>$url) {
    if(strpos($url, 'what you are looking for')) { unset($array[$key]); }
}
```

Comment: I explained a little more in the original question, maybe you get my point now.

Comment: I'm still really confused as to what you are looking for. Sounds like you want to keep an array of each subfolder in a session variable. explode(mysite.com/this/is/my/url, '/') to get the array and then use the foreach loop I provided to get rid of whatever you don't want.

Comment: O OK just as I left a comment :)

Comment: No. Since the site URL is taken from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and then put into an array, the array can modify itself when (for example) instead of root folder the site is in a sub-folder in which case it will include that folder name into an array making that array completely useless. But this foreach takes me exactly where I want to go.

Comment: `stpos()` is missing an r. And `strpos()` accepts 2 or 3 arguments. As a general practice, it's usually helpful to include a link to the PHP doc page for any function referenced in a post. Since PHP has great documentation, you just need to put the function name after `http://www.php.net/`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder You're right, sorry. I fixed the typos. Was doing this off the top of my head while trying to get an idea of what he wanted.